# Can't Undervolt Zephryus G14 CPU from the armory crate

Tags: laptop, asus-laptop, asus, asus-rog-zephyrus

Recently I learned how to undervolt my Zephyrus. I wanted to help my brother undervolt his Zephyrus, but I couldn’t find the option to do it in his armory crate. I thought it was because my Zephryus was a G15, but my friend that taught me had a G14. Then I thought it was because he had AMD Chip, but I remember my friend had an AMD Chip. Both are Ryzen 9s. My friends Ryzen 9 is a Ryzen 9 6900hs while my brother's is a Ryzen 9 4900HS.

Comment: I'm assuming that Armoury Crate only presents the options that are compatible with the system it is running on. Rather than "remembering" and telling this like a story, can you give a complete listing of the components in your brother's system, all in a clear list, so that we can tell which component's you're trying to do this on? Also, there appear to be a lot of guides on this online, so what research have you done?